# PowerShell 2.0 and Add-Content cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to use Add-Content cmdlet to add some text to .txt file.

```
Add-Content C:\scripts\test.txt "test"
```

Instead of "test" it add to the file some Asian alphabet symbols. I have found this thread for the same problem:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/9cdbeb30-d934-4ae1-8cba-d268224561e9

I tried to follow the steps there but without any success. Any ideas why this happens ?

Best regards,

Yordan Nikolov

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the way the original file was encoded. A quick workaround (and verification that this is an encoding issue) might be to open your .txt file in notepad and save it to test2.txt.
Then execute your command:

```
Add-Content C:\scripts\test2.txt "test"
```

and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi, it works. Thank you very much. I used notepad++ and the encoding was utf-8.